# mysql insert multiple records with common element using select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, a `User table`, a `Company table`, and a `linking table` that assigns user roles. I am trying to update the `user_role` table so that all users of their associated companies have the same role. The role table looks something like this:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| role_id | user_id | company_id |
+---------+---------+------------+
|       2 |      54 |         30 | 
|      15 |       1 |         15 | 
|      14 |      87 |         32 | 
|      15 |      88 |         33 | 
|      15 |     106 |          3 | 
+---------+---------+------------+
```

What I want to logically do is something like this

```
INSERT INTO user_role 
    (user_id, company_id, role_id) 
VALUES (
         (SELECT user_id FROM user_role WHERE company_id = ##FIRST COMPANY_ID IN LIST##), 
         (##LIST OF COMPANY_ID'S##), 2
       );
```

I have a static list of company_id's, and I want all users that have any role in that company to be assigned an additional static role_id in this table. What is the best way to accomplish this? Should I look at a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO user_role (user_id, company_id, role_id) 
SELECT user_id, company_id, { new role id here }
  FROM user_role 
 WHERE company_id in ( { list of company id's here })
```

Comment: This worked well with a minor modification! just added SELECT DISTINCT! thanks!

Comment: @Adunahay Doh, I should have anticipates that. You are welcome :-)